# request.session.get() doesnt retireve values between views in django views.py

Tags: django, vue.js, session

I want to pass the data of a client after he logged in, i use a login view to retrieve his data from the database then store it inside session variables, and after that i want to retrieve this data in another view, profile view in this case so i can take this data after i make a get request from a vue view after its mounted, but the issue here that the variable do not pass between the login view and the profile view.
Here is my login view :

```
@csrf_exempt  
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        
        gerant = Gerant.objects.filter(username=username, password=password).first()
        if gerant is not None:
            request.session['gerant_nom'] = gerant.nom
            request.session['gerant_prenom'] = gerant.prenom
            name = request.session.get('gerant_nom')
            print(f"name: {name}")
            return JsonResponse({'url': 'http://localhost:8080/profilgerant'})
```

the get request for the profile view:

```
  mounted(){
        axios
             .get('profile/')
             .then(
                response => {
                    this.nom = response.data.gerant_nom
                    this.prenom = response.data.gerant_prenom
                },
                console.log(this.nom)
             )
    }
```

the profile view:

```
@csrf_exempt  
def profile(request):
    gerant_nom = request.session.get('gerant_nom')
    gerant_prenom = request.session.get('gerant_prenom')
    print(f'nom: {gerant_nom}')
    data = {
        'gerant_nom': gerant_nom,
        'gerant_prenom': gerant_prenom
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

i want the data to be retrieved after the view is mounted.

Comment: Don't implement username and passwords yourself unless you're really sure you know what you're doing (and even then, still probably don't). This page of the Django docs will explain its built in authentication system: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/, and this page will explain middleware (which is how Django handles session, via its session middleware): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/ . But really, no custom solution unless you have a very good reason to do so